# A Tonelli type theorem for normal weight on a von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I got stuck with the following problem while reading Section 10.18 of 'Lectures on von Neumann algebras' by Strătilă and Zsidó.

**Problem:** Let $\varphi$ be a normal weight on a von Neumann algebra $\mathscr{M}$. Let $\{\sigma_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ be a group of automorphisms of $\mathscr{M}$. For $a\in\mathscr{M}^+$, we define $a_n=\sqrt{n/\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-nt^2}\sigma_t(a)\,dt,\;n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then show that $\varphi (a_n)=\sqrt{n/\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-nt^2}\varphi (\sigma_t(a))\,dt,\;n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Definition:** A weight $\varphi$ on a von Neumann algebra $\mathscr{M}$ is normal if there exists a family $\{\varphi_i\}$ of $w$-continuous (i.e. continuous with respect to the ultraweak topology on $\mathscr{M}$) positive forms on $\mathscr{M}$ such that $\varphi (a)=\sum_i\varphi_i (a),\;a\in\mathscr{M}^+$.

To solve the above problem, it is enough to show that $\sum_i\sqrt{n/\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-nt^2}\varphi_i(\sigma_t(a))\,dt=\sqrt{n/\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-nt^2}\sum_i\varphi_i(\sigma_t(a))\,dt$, and it almost seems like an application of [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), but here the summation $\sum_i$ can be an uncountable sum, which being not $\sigma$-finite, we can not apply Tonelli's theorem.

Note that I have changed the actual statement given in the book to reduce some technicality. To see the actual statement I got stuck in, see the highlighted part of this [attachment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rkcJ_eyWRU9I08YeIxDmziCPgbkhqERW/view?usp=sharing). Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Why is normality relevant?  (I'm not an expert on vN algebras.)  For any continuous linear functional $f$ on a Banach space $B$, trajectory $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}\to B$, and weights $w\in\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, we have $f\left(\int{w(t)\sigma(t)\,dt}\right)=\int{w(t)f(\sigma(t))\,dt}$ (assuming both integrals converge strongly).  Isn't your problem just a special case?

Comment: @JacobManaker My problem is to interchange a weight with an integral, and I want to show that normality of the weight ensures that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use directly that $\varphi$ is normal. The sequence
$$
b_k=\sqrt{\frac n\pi}\int_{-k}^ke^{-nt^2}\,\sigma_t(a)\,dt
$$
is increasing on $k$, and $\lim_kb_k=a_n$. Then the normality of $\varphi$ gives you
$$
\varphi(a_n)=\lim_k\varphi(b_k)=\sqrt{\frac n\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-nt^2}\,\varphi(\sigma_t(a))\,dt.
$$

Comment: How do you deduce the last equality?

Comment: $a_n=\sup_kb_k$, so $\varphi(a_n)=\sup_k\varphi(b_k)$.

Comment: I meant how do you deduce $\lim_k\varphi (b_k)=\sqrt{n/\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-nt^2}\sigma_t(a)\,dt$? I think it is not right. Please check it.

Comment: Yeah, a $\varphi$ was missing.

Comment: I am still not getting how did you deduce the final equality, i.e. $\lim_k\varphi(b_k)=\sqrt{n/\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-nt^2}\varphi(\sigma_t(a))\,dt$. Could you please elaborate that step?

Comment: The integrand is continuous. So if you take lower Darboux sums, you get the integral as a montone limit of positive operators, and you can use normality.